# How to use the Replace() function of Access with executeUpdate command in Java?

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I have used below code to replace a string by another string in `executeUpdate` method.The code is:

```
                  try
                  {
                   Connection cn=null;Statement st=null;
                  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                  String constring="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=D:sandeep\\copy of abcdef.mdb;";
                  cn=DriverManager.getConnection(constring, "", ""); 
                  st=cn.createStatement();
                  String sql="UPDATE temp SET mobile = Replace(mobile, '-', '')";
                  st.executeUpdate(sql.toString());
                  }
                 catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex);
                  }
```

The exception is:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Undefined  function 'Replace' in expression.

Comment: Does that SQL run manually?  I thought for functions you had to create a `CallableStatement`?

Answer (score 3):

`Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};` uses the older "Jet" database driver, and when using that driver the `Replace()` function is not available to queries executed from outside the Access application itself. In other words, that query will work if executed from *within Access*, but it will not work when executed from an external program like your Java application.

If you really need to use the `Replace()` function you could try installing the 32-bit version of the newer [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255) (a.k.a. "ACE"). The newer version of the driver allows `Replace()` (and other functions) to be used in places where the older driver did not.

I just tested this using the newer "ACE" driver and the following code works for me.

Note that the driver name is slightly different: `{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}`

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCQuery {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        try {
            String connectionString = null;
            connectionString = 
                    "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" + 
                    "DBQ=C:\\__tmp\\myDb.mdb;";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);

            st = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "UPDATE temp SET mobile = Replace(mobile, '-', '')";
            st = con.createStatement();
            st.execute(sql);
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (ps != null) {
                    ps.close();
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }
            } catch( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with this line only

Replace

```
String constring="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=D:sandeep\\copy of abcdef.mdb;";
```

By

```
String dbFileName="D:/sandeep/copy of abcdef.mdb";
String constring="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"+
                        "DBQ="+dbFileName+";";
```